# Execute child component's separate function while on Parent component with a click of a button

Tags: angular

Both my components are loaded on a single page

On component 2 I have a function that I want to be executed when I click a button on component 1

Is there any way to do this?

Comp 2 Function

```
EditValues(){
  let data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("requestId"));
  console.log(data);
  this.setResourceDTOS(data)
  this.myForm.patchValue(data);}
```

Comp 1 html

```
<td><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" (click)="editRequest(resource)" style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 30px" aria-hidden="true"> </i></td>
```

I want it to be executed after the editRequest() function

Comment: Depends first of all how these components are related to each other, but in any case, this part of documentation should answer your question: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: If I have a parent component and the child component is inside of it, is there any way to do this?

Comment: if the child tag is inside the parent, then you can use @Output from the child to tell parent to do whatever you want it to do. Otherwise using a service is a common way to communicate between components.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
<app-child #child></app-child>
```

```
<button (click)="child.callMethod()">Call</button>
```